# How do I install a newer swift-tools-version?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager, xcode11.6

I'm attempting to create a new Swift package for the first time.

According to [this Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/bundling_resources_with_a_swift_package), to create a package with bundled resources I need to be using `swift-tools-version:5.3` however my system defaults to `swift-tools-version:5.2`.

I've checked the Apple Developer downloads portal for related files as well as Apple's SPM repo on GitHub but don't see any direction or guidance on this subject.

I'm running `Xcode 11.6 (11E708)` on `Catalina 10.15.5 (19F101)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's bundled within Xcode. If you need `swift-tools-version:5.3`, you need to use Xcode 12.

The https://xcodereleases.com website is a good resource for understanding the Swift version that is bundled inside each version of Xcode.

Comment: what if I use debian/ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

What works for me is:

- open the last version of Xcode, or download the newest.
- This will download the latest released Swift version.
- Apparently there isn't a way to download the keychain separately or I did not find it.
- then in the settings in Xcode you select the new keychain under command line tools.
- Back to terminal you can use Swift 5.5 or the newest one!

[image: in the settings]

#### Another possibility

- Go to [Download Swift](https://www.swift.org/download/#snapshots)
  There you can see the releases and the snapshots with the latest Swift toolchains.
- Download the one for macOS.
- Once downloaded (around 800MB), double-click to launch the installer, then follow the on-screen instructions. Expect a full install to take up about 3.5GB.
- go to the Xcode menu in the top-left corner, and choose Toolchains
- You'll need to restart Xcode and then it will show that you have the latest one in the about Xcode menu.

[image: change the toolchain]