# How to install new `swift-tools-version` on macOS 10.15 which supports XCode 12.4

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

The title is pretty self explanatory but I'll try to provide some more context.

So I want to debug my macOS app on `macOS 10.15`, which appears to have some glitches. But i'm unable to make the project up and running because `macOS 10.15` supported version of XCode is 12.4, which comes with `swift-tools-version` 5.3. Most of the Swift Packages requires `swift-tools-version` 5.6 and newer and I haven't found a way to use newer version with `XCode 12.4`.

NOTE: Please don't confuse with Swift-toolchain, which is possible to update on older machines.

Comment: Don't confuse _building_ your app on Catilina (macOS 10.15) with _running_ your app on Catilina. You can build it on, say, Ventura, and try it out on your Catilina machine. (You can have two machines or you can use emulation of an older system on your Ventura machine.) But as you are probably implying by the word "debug", you won't be able to run it _from Xcode_ on Catilina. You will just have to run it (perhaps instrumented with oddles of logging) and see how it behaves, and try to fix it. An alternative is, of course, to drop support for an older system that you can no longer support.

Comment: Or you could split the development into two separate projects (and two separate apps), of course.

Comment: @matt you are totally correct, but the thing is if I were to get sources of the swift packages, put it into my source code, everything would work just fine.

Since there's the way to use latest swift toolchain, I assume that potentially there's a way to use latest swift-tool-version

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install a newer swift-tools-version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63404251/how-do-i-install-a-newer-swift-tools-version)

Comment: Unfortunately no, because macOS 10.15 doesn't support latest XCode, which has newer toolchain